# How can I add a (very) simple "Insert dialog" link?

Tags: 7, navigation, wysiwyg

I'm currently developing a social networking website and need a clean and simple editor for user content creation. I've choosen CKEditor (https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) as it is integrated in Drupal 8 and seems reliable. I know that one can also integrate it with Wysiwyg module, but I don't see any advantage in this approach and 1 module is better than 2 IMHO.

The problem is that all plugins offering "insert link" functionality that I have tested (original one, Linkit) are anything but simple. I understand that in many cases this rich functionality is good, but not in my case.

What I want to achieve is super-simple button like we have here on Stackexchange. Just link, it's title and nothing more. I tried to integrate http://ckeditor.com/addon/SimpleLink plugin but it doesn't work with my version of CKEditor.

Are there ways to simplify existing widgets?

Comment: I suggest to create a cstum text format. This way you can create e.g a simpel markdown syntax in your editor which is converted to links.